# C socket closed detection

Tags: c, sockets

I am reading this post about [How to detect when the client closes the connection](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/conn_closed.html)

But when I run the code in this post (pasted it below):

```
fd = accept(listenSocket);
pid_t childProcess = fork();
if (childProcess == (pid_t)-1) {
    perror("Unable to create new process for client connection");
    exit(1);
}
else if (childProcess == 0) {
    // read from socket, process queries, etc.
}
else {
    // use the poll system call to be notified about socket status changes
    struct pollfd pfd;
    pfd.fd = fd;
    pfd.events = POLLIN | POLLHUP | POLLRDNORM;
    pfd.revents = 0;
    while (pfd.revents == 0) {
        // call poll with a timeout of 100 ms
        if (poll(&pfd, 1, 100) > 0) {
            // if result > 0, this means that there is either data available on the
            // socket, or the socket has been closed
            char buffer[32];
            if (recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0) {
                // if recv returns zero, that means the connection has been closed:
                // kill the child process
                kill(childProcess, SIGKILL);
                waitpid(childProcess, &status, WNOHANG);
                close(fd);
                // do something else, e.g. go on vacation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When client disconnected, above logic (in server side) never run into the last else statement at all. so that logic actually do not possible to detect disconnection.

Is this correct post now for socket disconnect detection?

Comment: At a first look it seems fine to me... are you sure that a client originated closure occurs? Just to know: why don't you simply check for recv( )==0 in the father process where you seem to ` // read from socket, process queries, etc`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure client disconnect the connection. check recv will be done in the connection success code block, but the post is talking about the else block. so I think if connection sucess, the else block should never been hit.  and check recv 0 is good. Now I want to understand the post logic!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it under linux with

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

My detection is working for many years. The socket is a server. Detection is with the return-code of recv.

```
...
cl = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_clnt, (socklen_t *) &len);
unsigned char c;
for (;;)
{
    int ret = recv (cl, &c, 1, MSG_DONTWAIT);

    if (ret == 1)
    {
        // 1 byte received
        ..
    }
    else if (ret == -1) // socket open but no data
    {
        // socket open but no data
        ...
    }
    else 
    {
        // ret = 0, socket opened but now client left
        ...
    }
    // sleep
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: this logic do not fork process so maybe not the same as original posts.